# Is dependence of one classification on another a violation of the assumption of independence for ANOVA?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, modeling, independence

My subjects are mice, swimming in a pool for 60 s.  The DV is how much time they spend in each quadrant of the pool.  The performance of each subject is independent of every other subject.  However, the software classifies each 0.5-s frame as being in one of the four quadrants.  If the subject is in one quadrant he is by definition not in the other three quadrants.  The typical way to analyze these data is with repeated-measures ANOVA, with each quadrant a measure, but this doesn't seem right to me if each of the observations in each quadrant is dependent on what happened in the other three quadrants.  Am I thinking about this right or is repeated-measures ANVOVA OK in this case?